# I can't debug my ASP.NET app locally because Chrome rejects the page as not secure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, https

I'm trying to build and test a ASP.NET Core MVC web app on my PC usuing Visual Studio 2022 and with HTTPS selected for the solution/project.

However, when I run the debug, the local host web page comes up with Your  connection is not private attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).

How do I get around this. Or do I have to start over and not select to use HTTPS when I create the solution/project?